# Matlab coder for converting feature extraction functions

Tags: c, matlab, extract, matlab-deployment, matlab-coder

Currently I face this problem:
I need to obtain ( .c ) versions of `(extractHOGFeatures(x), extractLBPFeatures(x), rgb2hsv(x), imhist (x))` functions which exist in computer vision toolbox. Because I need the same output of these Matlab functions to use it in android app.
So is Matlab coder will help me? Is it work well to converting these Matlab functions?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how good the results from the coder will be, but in this [list](http://de.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/functions-supported-for-code-generation--categorical-list.html) of functions supported for Code Generation only rgb2hsv is not included.